# How can I pass variable while using dict.get() method in for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I am new to Python and I am work on one small assignment. I am getting issue while passing variable in `dict.get()` method in Python.

Here is the code sample which I am using :

```
inputFile = open("Result_table_file.txt")

outputFile = open("Result.txt","w")

file =  open("matadata.txt")

from collections import defaultdict
d =  defaultdict(dict)

for line in file:
    name,values = line.split(':',1)
    d[name] = values

for record in inputFile:
    recordSplit = record.split(",")
    filename = recordSplit[3]
    metadataValue = d.get(filename)
    print "FileName :" + filename
    print metadataValue
    print "Record : " + record
```

Output is :

```
FileName : Image01.tif
Metadata : None
Record : 100,134423.0,13911111,Image01
```

This code works fine. The only issue is when I pass `filename` variable to `metadataValue = d.get(filename)` method it gives me result as `None`.

Can anybody suggest me what could be the issue and how can I resolve it.

There is one more thing that I have identified , when I create the filename variable manually instead for getting value from the file. It is working fine.

for example :

filename = "Image01" 
d.get(filename)

I am getting correct output whereas if I get value while reading the file this thing doesn't works.

For example

for record in inputFile:
     recordSplit = record.split(",") 
     filename = recordSplit[3] 
     metadataValue = d.get(filename) 
     print "FileName :" + filename 
     print metadataValue 
     print "Record : " + record

Any Idea?

Comment: The point of `d.get(f)` over `d[f]` is that you get `None` instead of an exception if it doesn't exist. You probably don't want to be using it.

Comment: Also, have you tried putting `print(d)` after the first `for` loop? What do you get?

Comment: Do you expect every entry in Result_table_file.txt to have a corresponding entry in metadata.txt? (btw, naming a variable `file` is a mildly bad idea, since it shadows a built-in. granted, a built-in no one uses...)

Comment: As a final note, you should always close files when you open them, and you should only keep them open for the shortest period of time possible. To help, it would make sense to [use `with` to open files](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Comment: Yes if have tried to print it but d.get(filename) is None

Comment: Yes, I expect every entry in Result_table_file.txt to have a corresponding entry in metadata.txt

Comment: @user2187356 What do you get when you `print(d)`. I know you get `None` from `d.get(filename)` - but why you get that will depend on the content of `d` and `filename` - print them both and paste the results into an edit on your question, it will help find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If `d[filename]` does not exist, then `get` will return `None`.

Add a second argument to return as a default if `d[filename]` does not exist:

```
In [2]: d = {'a':1, 'b':2}

In [7]: print d.get('a')
1

In [8]: print d.get('c')
None

In [9]: print d.get('c', 77)
77
```

Comment: This presumes that `filename` not existing in `d` is desired, and not a bug.

Comment: d[filename] returning None where as if I pass the value of filename which is "Image01" in that case it returns the value.

Comment: that means d[filename] is exists.

Comment: There is one more thing that I have identified , when I create the filename variable manually instead for getting value from the file. It is working fine.

for example :

filename = "Image01" d.get(filename)

I am getting correct output whereas if I get value while reading the file this thing doesn't works

For example

for record in inputFile: recordSplit = record.split(",") filename = recordSplit[3] metadataValue = d.get(filename) print "FileName :" + filename print metadataValue print "Record : " + record

Any Idea?

Comment: +1. But actually, he's using `d =  defaultdict(dict)`, which means he doesn't even need to do `d.get(key, defvalue)`; he can just use `d[key]`.

Answer (score 0):

When we call get method on dict with an unexist key, the method will return None.
In your case, it means that d doesn't have a key named filename. 
And I guess the problem is that you should replace  by
. 
You open an unexist file and read from it, and then put what you read into d.So d is juse None.So d doesn't have a key name filename.

Comment: but when I pass actually filename value instead of filename variable than it has the key that means key is exist.

Comment: There is one more thing that I have identified , when I create the filename variable manually instead for getting value from the file. It is working fine.

for example :

filename = "Image01" d.get(filename)

I am getting correct output whereas if I get value while reading the file this thing doesn't works

For example

for record in inputFile: recordSplit = record.split(",") filename = recordSplit[3] metadataValue = d.get(filename) print "FileName :" + filename print metadataValue print "Record : " + record

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I see some inconsistency here.

How it is possible that `record` is equal to `100,134423.0,13911111,Image01`, while `filename`, which is calculated by `record.split(",")[3]`, is equal to `Image01.tif`?

If `filename` is really equal to `Image01.tif` and the `d` contains an entry for the key `Image01`, not `Image01.tif`, then you will get `None`.

As someone suggested you should print the `d` and `filename` before calculating `metadataValue` to see what's happening.

**EDIT**:

OK, lines from file include (at least on my computer) a trailing `\n` character, which may be invisible when printing. Try to do `filename.strip()` before the get call.

Comment: sorry its my typo mistake record = 00,134423.0,13911111,Image01.tif

Comment: @user2187356 I have added my next idea as an edit to my first post.